# SQLite create trigger error with DEFAULT VALUES

Tags: triggers, sqlite

Following the sqlite documentation: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html I created a very simple trigger on even simpler database table (using SQLite3 database):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
users_ids 
(
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
status INTEGER DEFAULT 0
)
```

And the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER addID
AFTER UPDATE OF status
ON users_ids
WHEN NEW.status > 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO users_ids DEFAULT VALUES;
END
```

This gives me error regarding the `DEFAULT` keyword. If I change the `INSERT` to this:

```
INSERT INTO users_ids (status) VALUES (0);
```

Then it works. But since the documentation mentions the DEFAULT VALUES clearly as an option for `INSERT` (except for insert trigger) then I see no reason why it gives me this error. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users_ids ...
 AFTER UPDATE OF status ON user_ids ...
               INSERT INTO user_id ...
```

Please make a decision what the name of that table actually is.

Furthermore, the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) says:

> The "INSERT INTO *table* DEFAULT VALUES" form of the INSERT statement is not supported.

Comment: Regarding the edit: Yes, I misread that. I understood it that it applies only for INSERT triggers and not for all triggers. That explains it. Thanks!